# Biber and main file compilation

Tags: biber

I am using the subfile package to make a considerably huge document where the arrangement is as follows:

```
- The main folder containing a "Main.tex" file.

- Another folder inside the main folder containing all the subfiles.
```

Upon running biber for the subfiles, it caughts the citations correctly, yet when I try to compile the main file, it generates the following:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
INFO - Found 58 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'With_all_set_up.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'With_all_set_up.bib' to With_all_set_up.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'With_all_set_up.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'With_all_set_up.bib'
WARN - ISBN '19127' in entry 'Shaker' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
WARN - ISBN '6-3227-90-977-978' in entry 'Eshak2015' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
WARN - ISBN '0521299780 9780521299787' in entry 'Browning1983' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
WARN - ISBN '9772320777' in entry 'Omar1970' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
WARN - ISBN '977-5109-76-D' in entry 'Demit2012' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
WARN - ISBN '9970165418' in entry 'Misc1886' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
WARN - ISBN '2-162-241-977' in entry 'Andreas2015' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash:
```

If I have a bad entry, then Biber wouldn't have run in the subfiles, it wouldn't have cited the references correctly. So, are there any suggestions?
THe contents of the *.BLG file for one of the subfiles are as follows:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[1] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'chapter5.blg'
[250] biber-MSWIN32:322> INFO - === 
[400] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'chapter5.bcf'
[703] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 6 citekeys in bib section 0
[768] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[769] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'With_all_set_up.bib'
[898] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'With_all_set_up.bib' to With_all_set_up.bib
[1437] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'With_all_set_up.bib' for section 0
[1677] bibtex.pm:1653> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[2187] bibtex.pm:1471> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'With_all_set_up.bib'
[2906] Utils.pm:304> WARN - ISBN '2-162-241-977' in entry 'Andreas2015' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
[3098] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'ar-001' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[3098] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'ar-001' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[3098] Biber.pm:4084> INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'ar-001'
[3123] bbl.pm:652> INFO - Writing 'chapter5.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[3162] bbl.pm:755> INFO - Output to chapter5.bbl
[3163] Biber.pm:128> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

Upon researhing the file, the issue was found to be caused by the following reference:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
@online{Wikivowelfile2019,
 author = {,Wikimedia Commons},
 title = {Daniel Jones's 18 Cardinal Vowels},
 year = 2019,
 url = {https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Daniel_Jones%27s_18_Cardinal_Vowels.svg},
 urldate = {2018-08-16},
 langid = {english},
 keywords = {English}
}
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
It is caused by the URL component since it contains the "%" character. Upon removing the URL component, the file runs without issues.
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Are you sure biber is using the same bib-file in all cases? What does the log of a biber run on one of the subfiles shows?

Comment: don't confuse bib bbl and blg. These are different file endings.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/5oaq1fpjd103c63/chapter5.blg/file

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/t8h8ggpvmvf2aqk/chapter4.blg/file

Comment: I couldn't open the files so I uploaded them

Comment: You can simply open them in your editor. These are normal text-files. But don't double click on them (at least not in windows).

Comment: aren't you long enough here to know that you can edit your question?

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused, I edited the question (added the contents of the blog file) above

Comment: as you can see biber is processing a different set of entries. So it is quite possible that it chokes on one only if the main file is handled.  You will have to debug your bib-file.

Comment: Meaning that I have to remove all the entries from the *.bib file, then add them one by one and compile after each time I add an entry so as to get the source of the issue?

Comment: well I would split the bib in two parts and so on. That's faster.

Comment: One of the references has the following entry: url = {https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Daniel_Jones%27s_18_Cardinal_Vowels.svg}, it used to work before, but now it does not and is causing an issue, any suggestions? To be more specific, the web site adress has the symbol % which adds what's after it as a comment

Comment: Make a small, complete example

Comment: Example added above

Comment: The problem is not the url, but the comma at the begin of the author field. Remove it.